# Why am I not arriving at the right solution for this Taylor series?

Tags: calculus

*This is a problem from Khan Academy's Integral Calculus section*

Let $g(x)=e^{ 2x+2 }$ and let ${ T }_{ 3 }(x)$ be the third-degree Taylor polynomial for $g$ centered at $x=0$. The sum of the coefficients of ${ T }_{ 3 }(x)$ can be written as $ae^{2}$. Determine $a$.

So far, I have learned that if you have a function that is not so "pleasant" to take the derivative of, you can take the an easier function and then substitute the other features of the original function into the taylor polynomial of the easier one. For example:

$$f(x)=x^{ 3 }cos(x^{ 2 })$$
$$g(x)=cos(x)$$ 
$$g(x)=cos(x)\approx 1-\frac { x^{ 2 } }{ 2! } +\frac { x^{ 4 } }{ 4! } -\frac { x^{ 6 } }{ 6! } +...$$

$$f(x)=x^{ 3 }g(x^{ 2 })\approx x^{ 3 }(1-\frac { (x^{ 2 })^{ 2 } }{ 2! } +\frac { (x^{ 2 })^{ 4 } }{ 4! } -\frac { (x^{ 2 })^{ 6 } }{ 6! } +...)$$

I am not trying to apply this to the problem I was given. I have $g(x)=e^{ 2x+2 }$ and I want to use $h(x)=e^{ x }$ to simplify the problem for myself. 
So I have:

$$h(x)=e^{ x }\approx 1+x+\frac { x^{ 2 } }{ 2! } +\frac { x^{ 3 } }{ 3! } +...$$

$$g(x)=h(2x+2)=e^{ 2x+2 }\approx 1+(2x+2)+\frac { (2x+2)^{ 2 } }{ 2! } +\frac { (2x+2)^{ 3 } }{ 3! } +...$$

This doesn't seem right to me. Where am I going wrong? No actual solution, please. I want to get it on my own.

Comment: Note: you *have* found the Taylor series about $x=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that $2x+2$ does not go to $0$ (where the Taylor series applies) as $x\to 0$. Put differently, you want to apply the Taylor expansion of $\exp$ at $0$ to a function $y(x)$, when $x\to 0$. To do that, you must have $y(x)\to 0$... For the approach to work, consider instead
$$
e^{2x+2} = e^2e^{2x} = e^2\left(1+2x+\frac{(2x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(2x)^3}{3!}+o(x^3)\right)
$$
which this time holds because $2x\to 0$ when $x\to0$.